# Referencing custom jQuery Widget instances from outside jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, widget

I have many custom-made jQuery widgets. I look for a way to hold a reference to their underlaying widget-object instances so I could use them (invoke methods) without traversing through my DOM using jQuery to find them first.

Also: any good ideas for positioning widget-specific enumeration variables?

Answer (score 0):

I think answer (jQuery UI) is what you're looking for: [jQuery plugin: publicly accessible functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882358/jquery-plugin-publicly-accessible-functions/4882578#4882578)